# Can't run my Flutter project (also new project)

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Not long ago, I had a problem with flutter overnight, so I decided to uninstall flutter, dart and gradle. Despite having reinstalled everything, check that the environment variables were correct with --version, I still have errors but different. Depending on what I'm trying to do I have different errors that I put below.

Error when i run main.dart :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_email_sender:compileDebugKotlin'.
Compilation error. See log for more details
```

Error when i try ./gradlew clean in android directory of project:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Unable to get mutable Windows environment variable map
```

Error when i try gradle build:

```
> Configure project :app
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'false'
Consider disabling R8 by removing 'android.enableR8=true' from your 
gradle.properties before publishing your app.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\cleme\OneDrive\Bureau\Ptut\xflop\android\app\build.gradle'                     line: 25

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not initialize class   org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.DefaultKotlinSourceSetKt

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
```

My tools version :

- Flutter 2.8.0
- Dart 2.15.0
- Gradle 7.3.1 (I also tried with gradle 6.7.1 with same result)

Answer (score 0):

Please update your kotlin version like this below way

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"//update with latest version
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

}
```

}

Comment: Hello, my kotlin version was 1.3.50, i update it to 1.3.72 but i still have errors